# How would I go about achieving multiple inputs - within if statements - with list comprehension in Python

Tags: python

I've recently taken to learning list comprehension and have found it extremely useful. However, I just now ran into the fact that I apparently cannot chain if statements with inputs - not sure what the syntax on this is. For example, this previous dictionary-append code I had made works fine (in which the if else clause is only to make it add \n into the statement when the first input has passed:

```
key = list(
str(input(f"Please enter a Key for value {x + 1}: "))
if x == 0
else str(input(f"\nPlease enter a Key for value {x + 1}: "))
for x in range(3))
```

However, when writing a code to append the date to a list through comprehension I learned that I cannot just write:

```
date = list(str(input('Please enter the year: ')) 
        if x == 0 str(input('Please enter the year: ')) 
        elif x == 1 else str(input('Please enter the day: ')) 
        for x in range(3))
```

So I'm just wondering how to write:

```
date = []

for i in range(3):
if i == 0:
    date.append(str(input("Please enter the year: ")))
elif i == 1:
    date.append(str(input("\nPlease enter the month: ")))
else:
    date.append(str(input("\nPlease enter the day: ")))
```

Using list comprehension.

Comment: It would be possible to write this in a list comprehension but I can't help wondering why you'd want to do that. A loop would be much easier to read/maintain

Comment: @JCaesar that's fair, I just want to further my knowledge I guess, it's not so much about the actual task in this case. I'd like to know the limits, and possibilities - this is just an example I've run into.

Comment: See my answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two methods. In my opinion, the loop is better if only because it's more readable. I have no doubt that others will disagree but here goes anyway:

```
date = []

for t in ['year', 'month', 'day']:
    v = input(f'Please enter the {t}:')
    date.append(v)

print(date)

date = [input(f'Please enter the {t}:') for t in ['year', 'month', 'day']]

print(date)
```